# Angular Dropdown menu does not show default value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

With regular html select menus, if you create an option element with `selected` and `disabled` attributes and give that option text, then that text will display in the select menu by default. Here is basic html:

```
<select name="myname">
  <option selected disabled>Select one...</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

This is what pages looks like:

[image]

But in the below isolated code, I demonstrate that Angular is intrusively not showing the option text:

https://github.com/lovefamilychildrenhappiness/DropDownNoShowDefaultValue

```
// app.component.html
<h1>Select Box does not show default value: </h1>
<app-select-box
  [options]="collection"
></app-select-box>

// select-box.component.html
<select 
    [value]="value" 
    [disabled]="disabled">
    <option selected disabled value="">Select one...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

What is causing Angular to disrupt the native html behavior of select boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your select `value` is bound to a variable called `value` which is undefined initially. As per the html, there is no `option` with a value of `undefined`, so nothing gets selected. Your `Select one...` option has an empty string value. So to fix this, initialize `value` in your component to an empty string.

```js
value: string = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the option to be selected in the first place.

```
<option value="0">value to be selected<option>
<option value="1">next<option>
<option value="2">Continues<option>
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything different. Have you tried git cloning the project I added? It is very small project that isolates this problem. I tried copying your code and it did not change anything.